# Difference between .scaledToFit() and .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Is there any difference between `.scaledToFit()` and `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference.
From Apple developer [`scaledToFit()`](https://scaledToFit()):

> This method is equivalent to calling [`aspectRatio(_:contentMode:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/aspectratio(_:contentmode:)-6j7xz) with a *nil* aspectRatio and a content mode of [`ContentMode.fit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/contentmode/fit).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scaledtofit()
This method is equivalent to calling aspectRatio(_:contentMode:)